# Java equality check and dispatch algorithms

Tags: java

Sometimes in my code, I have to check if a certain variable equals a constant string. For example:

```
if (foo.equals("CONST")) {
    stuff.do();
}
```

Sometimes foo is `null` so I get a null pointer exception. One workaround is to simply swap the object and the parameter around like so:

```
if ("CONST".equals(foo)) {
    stuff.do();
}
```

I have read that this is to do with Java being a single dispatch language but I don't see why. If `foo` is null, you will be calling a method on a null object which results in a null pointer exception. What does it have to do with single dispatch (or multiple dispatch, dynamic dispatch etc)? Is this problem related to any sort of dispatch concept?

Comment: You aren't calling a method on a null foo; you're calling it on a non-null instance of String with value "CONST".  The argument to the equals method happens to be null.  The override of equals for String deals with the null parameter properly.  You're making it too complicated - nothing to do with dispatch.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question. Where did you read that Java being a single-dispatch language had to do with no `NullPointerException` being thrown in the second snippet?

Comment: @Tunaki Sorry I'm not sure this was a long time ago. I recently came across this again.

Answer (score 1):

Not exactly, in the first case you are calling method equals for null which causes the problem, in the second case you are calling for "CONST" which is not null, foo is just a parameter and equals will not be called for it.

Answer (score 1):

1. Java is not a single dispatch language. It has a multiple dispatch
   mechanism, aka method overloading.
2. You are right that dispatch has no effect in the case of the exmaple code.

Comment: Wiki says Java is a single dispatch language: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_dispatch#Java

Comment: I relied on this article http://isagoksu.com/2009/single-dynamic-multiple-and-double-dispatching/ which defines multi dispatch as synonym for overloading. perhaps it is wrong?

Comment: That article also says `BTW, Java doesn't support true multiple dispatching, so don't cause any bugs while creating overloaded methods.`

Answer (score 0):

What you've read is simply about every object being extension from Object.class.
In practice this means that you can make only one hierarchy line from Object.class to your latest implementation of Custom.class extends Object.class.

But null is not Object.

That means you cannot use Dispatch mechanism on null and when it finds null reference it throws NullPointerException.

This has nothing to do with java in particular, just with how dispatch mechanism works (multiple or single type)

ps: in some languages you can create Class that extends from more than one superClass. Java didn't do that to avoid diamond problem (you extend from 2 classes that have same name for method. Compiler looks that they do different things and doesn't know how to choose between two so it shoots itself in the head), but I've heard that in Java 8 you now can hit that problem again :)

Answer (score 0):

JAVA supports **dynamic dispatching** which is nothing but "**Run time Polymerphism**".

***Cause of exception in your code:***

- As pointed out by others the first code does not work because you are
  calling "equals" method on "NULL"
- You must have declared "foo" like below : **String foo=null**;
- See here "**foo**" is a variable of reference type "**String**" but it refers
  to "null" not a "String" object. However As "**foo**" is a String type compiler allows you to call
  "**equals**" method on it. It doesn't give compile time error
- But when you run the code and if "**foo**" is still NULL, JVM will
  try to call "**equals**" on a null object. So it spits out "**NULL
  POINTER EXCEPTION**"

***Probable Solutions:***

You can use one of the below solutions or both of them.

- Initialize "**foo**" like this    **String foo=new String();**
- Make a *NULL check*

  ```
       if(foo!=null)
      {
      if(foo.equals("Constant"))
      {
          System.out.println("TRUE");
      }
      }
      else
      {
          System.out.println("NULL");
      }
  ```